# Define a variable with two sets of values

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to define my variable with two sets of values. For example,

```
Dim i as integer
For i = 92 to 97 and 104 to 109
```

Can you explain the proper way to do this? Here is what I have -

```
Dim k As Integer
For k = 92 To 97

If Range("A" & k).Text = "#NUM!" Then

Range("A" & k).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("I" & k).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("J" & k).Select
Selection.ClearContents

End If

Next k


Dim j As Integer
For j = 104 To 109

If Range("A" & k).Text = "#NUM!" Then

Range("A" & j).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("I" & j).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("J" & j).Select
Selection.ClearContents

End If

Next j
```

I'd like to combine variables k and j. Thanks!

Comment: You can reuse k on the second for loop. You can put the stuff inside into a sub procedure if you only want it written once. You could have a single loop ang call the sub twice per loop SubName(k) and SubName(k+12). It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim k As Integer
For k = 92 To 109
    If Range("A" & k).Text = "#NUM!" and (k <= 97 or k >= 104) Then
        Range("A" & k).ClearContents
        Range("I" & k).ClearContents
        Range("J" & k).ClearContents
    End If
Next k
```

This seems to me like the logical way to go. I also cleaned up all those selects. They are unnecessary and can cause you trouble more than anything.

Comment: yep also Range("A" & k, "I" & k, "J" & k).ClearContents